# Strange UITabBarItem positioning

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I'm trying to make a custom Tab Bar. I've used the setFinishedSelectedImage:finishedUnselectedImage: method which deletes apple's default glossy effect on the uitabbaritems. Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self customizeInterface];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] tag:1];
    [viewController1 setTabBarItem:tab1];
    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    [tab1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news.png"]];
    _tabBarController.tabBarItem = item;

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarItem *tab2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] tag:2];
    [viewController2 setTabBarItem:tab2];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    [tab2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_programme.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_programme.png"]];
    _tabBarController.tabBarItem = item1;


    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarItem *tab3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] tag:3];
    [viewController3 setTabBarItem:tab3];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    [tab3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_map.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_map.png"]];
    _tabBarController.tabBarItem = item2;

    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarItem *tab4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] tag:4];
    [tab4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_venues.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_venues.png"]];
    [viewController4 setTabBarItem:tab4];
    UITabBarItem *item3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    [item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_venues.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_venues.png"]];
    _tabBarController.tabBarItem = item3;

     UIViewController *viewController5 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarItem *tab5 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] tag:5];
    [viewController5 setTabBarItem:tab5];
    UITabBarItem *item4 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

    [tab5 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_more.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_more.png"]];
    _tabBarController.tabBarItem = item4;

    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,
                                     viewController2,
                                     viewController3,
                                     viewController4,
                                     viewController5, nil];


    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)customizeInterface
{
    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_bodyreal.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];

    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_object_current.png"]];

}
```

The problem is that the icons ports above the tab-bar.
Any ideas?

Thanks

[image: TabBar]

Comment: what do you mean with above tab-bar ?

Answer (score 0):

You should only set the tabbaritem property of the corresponding UIViewConroller.Remove the lines.

```
_tabBarController.tabBarItem = itemx;
```

apart from that optimal resolution for tabbar items shoudl be 30x30 pixel.

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Comment: Look at my edit (the picture). I don't really understand what you mean with set the tabbaritem property of the corresponding UIViewConroller.Remove the lines.?

Comment: what is your icon resolution it seems to be bigger than 30x30

Comment: I mean you do not set the tabbaritem property of the tabbar contorller. Remove the lines     _tabBarController.tabBarItem = item; for all items

Comment: Ok, I've deleted all the _tabBarController.tabBarItem = item; lines. But it doesn't make any changes...

Comment: what is the resolution of the images?They need to be 30x30 and 60x60 for Retina display in tabbatItemIcon@2x.png